# Convert Python Strings into Json

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to write a program that allows a user to input Questions and Answer for a multi-choice quiz. The questions and answers need to be written to a file in json format.

So far I have code that will ask the user for a Question, the correct answer to the question, then 3 incorrect answers, and write all the strings to a file. But I don't know how to convert the strings to json so they can be used in the Quiz.

The Code I have so far is:

```
def addToList(filename, data):
question = input('Add Question: ')   # prompt user to type what to add
correct = input('Add Correct Answer: ')
wrong1 = input('Add 1st Incorrect Answer: ')
wrong2 = input('Add 2nd Incorrect Answer: ')
wrong3 = input('Add 3rd Incorrect Answer: ')
question = question + '\n'      # add a line break to the end

correct = 'correct: ' + correct
wrong1 = 'wrong1: ' + wrong1
wrong2 = 'wrong2: ' + wrong2
wrong3 = 'wrong3: ' + wrong3



data.append(question)       # append the question
data.append(correct)
data.append(wrong1)
data.append(wrong2)
data.append(wrong3)


f = open(filename, 'a') # open the file in append mode
f.write(question)           # add the new item to the end of the file
f.write(correct)
f.write(wrong1)
f.write(wrong2)
f.write(wrong3)

f.close()
```

Sorry, I know this is a newbie problem but I'm totally lost here and can't find any examples of user input being put into Json.

Comment: Use a library like jsonpickle https://jsonpickle.github.io/

Answer (score 4):

First you build a `dictionary`, then convert it to `JSON`.

Like this:

```
import json
# (...)
correct = 'correct: ' + correct
wrong1 = 'wrong1: ' + wrong1
wrong2 = 'wrong2: ' + wrong2
wrong3 = 'wrong3: ' + wrong3

dic = {'correct': correct, 'wrong1': wrong1, 'wrong2': wrong2, 'wrong3': wrong3}
json_str = json.dumps(dic)
```